Grant-SMBShareAccess not working. Getting "The Request is Not Supported"
Got a strange one. I have about 40 servers with shares configured through SMB. This is my first time adding permissions to the shares after their original creation (years ago). For testing and troubleshooting I created a test group and account. However, the format I grabbed from the Microsoft KB doesn't seem to work after multiple attempts. Here is my example:
Grant-SMBShareAccess -Name "L$" -AccountName "turnips\Test Account" -AccessRight Full

After trying to execute this I am only met with this error:
> Grant-SMBShareAccess: The request is not supported At line:1 char:1
> + Grant-SMBShareAccess -Name "L$" -AccountName "turnips\Test Account" - ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (MSFT_SmbShare (...copeName = "*":ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/SMB/MSFT_SMB
>     Share) [Grant-SmbShareAccess], CimException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows Systems Error 50,Grant-SmbShareAccess

Any articles I have found online for this error have not been for exactly the same scenario, and the ones I found did not offer any help in this instance.
I've been trying to troubleshoot this all day, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

It might be due to the hidden admin share of the "L" drive though. Setup an alias share for the folder or drive as L1$ and consider not granting full but "change" perhaps unless those in the group will be admins, I believe FULL will allow permission to change share permission, whereas "change" gives them modify access to things in the share, but not permission to change ACL permissions, etc. of the share. If they are technical admins, it may be fine in your case, if problems arise otherwise, see if the share permissions where changed by those with FULL access to the share.

I'll give this a try after the weekend. To get them access for now I just setup standard Windows shares to the folder they needed. Would like to harness the correct way to do this to integrate this into builds and future setups easier, though. Will let you know what I find out!
